# Access inline C++ function from C

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to create C funciton wrappers for C++ and my goal is to make them inline. All the solutions on the internet say that when making an inline function in a library, just put the function definition in the header file. This won't work in this case though, since the functions contain code that will only compile in C++.

This example demonstrates the situation:

```
// box_c.cpp
#include "box.h"

extern "C" Square *new_Square(int width, int height){
    return new Square(width, height);
}



// box_c.h
void *new_Square(int width, int height);



// main.c
#include "box_c.h"

int main(void){
    void *s = new_Square(5, 5);
}
```

Wold it be possible to make `new_Square` inline in this case? (The wrapper is a static library).

Comment: `box_c.h` should protect itself from recursive include with a header guard.  It should also check if compiled as C or C++, and if compiled as C++ should have an `extern "C" {` ... `}`.  You should compile this code to make sure your example works.

Comment: Your example cannot work, inline or not, because the same function cannot return both `Square *` and `void *`.

Comment: @Eljay It was a rough example, so i missed a lot of the details. I meant to have "extern "C"" in the wrapper source and include gaurds in the header.

Comment: @n.m.```void*``` is compatible with any pointer type in C, so it would work fine. The header file shown is meant to be used by C programs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inlining means the compiler of the source where it is inlined needs to understand it on some level. C compilers don't understand C++ `new`. You can't do this. Leave it non-inlined, so a compiled version of the code can be linked without the compiler needing to understand C++ natively.

If the code (both library and final executable) is compiled with LTO enabled, it's possible the linker might inline the code at that point, but there are no guarantees there.

Comment: Linking to the wrapper as a static library with ```-flto``` did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously in general you cannot inline C++ code inside C code, they are two different languages.

So, either

- force the explicit instantiation of the C++ function in the compiled library,
- ensure that the C++ function is code-compatible with C and leave it in the header file as inline.

Comment: I can't make the C++ function code-compatible with C since I'm trying to wrap a 3rd-party library which I have no controll over. How would I force the export of the C++ function in the compiled binary?

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT: you can write C++ wrapper code that defines extern "C" functions that merely call the inline functions, like you did if I am right. But it does not make sense to make the wrapper functions inline.

Comment: @SamuelAmmoniusSTUDENT: To be clear, you can't *force* what you want to happen to happen. You have to write the code in a way that the C compiler only sees C-compatible source code or headers. Your code contains C++-only stuff (e.g. `new`), so it *must not* be visible to the C compiler (and therefore can't be `inline`). If inlining happens, it happens at link time, and you don't have direct control over whether or not it happens.